# Symfony2 Classloader warning

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

This warning shows up **half of the time** when the pages in the project load. So this doesn't show up on every page load. I have tried updating composer, cleared cache,etc.
I have no idea why this started a month ago.
I use Symfony 2.3.18, PHP 5.3.3-7

Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object in /www/current/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 195

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItjbX.png

[EDIT]

I also would like to note that in production this Error/Warning doesn't show.

Comment: Have you tried composer auto-upgrade and eventually minimal stability in composer.json? EDIT: For me, it looks like an issue with composer an/or symfony (I think composer uses it as well) and could be some issue there?

Comment: You should remove the `XMod\CommonBundle` from your `AppKernel` or fix the path. Maybe that will help. (see last error message)

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov I have done "composer update", and "minimum-stability": "alpha". I also just set the stability to stable.

Comment: @ferdynator This path has been in the project for ages before the warning started. Can't remove it and the path is correct.

Comment: Why would it throw the error if the path is correct? Is the `XMod Bundle` installed (are all files in the `vendor/` directory)?

Comment: Have you ever considered updating the PHP version? You would get performance improvements for free!

Comment: @ferdynator I have no idea why it shows the warning, it does work again when i refresh though! :S I get the warning 75% of the time (when i don't change code mind you)

Comment: @Sven That would be great for plenty of reasons :) I'll annoy my system engineers ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We restarted Apache/PHP to clear the APC cache.